# systemctl reload networking no longer works on buster

Tags: debian, networking, systemd, systemd-networkd

On Jessie, the command

```
sudo systemctl reload networking
```

runs without any complaints. On Buster, it fails with

> Failed to reload networking.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit networking.service.

What should be done instead?

<sub>(and why is this so? I could not find an easy answer in the systemd docs. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS#L474 mentions that you can reload, but it seems to no longer work)</sub>

Comment: Are you trying to restart the service? If yes, reload is not the way to do it. Even if it worked on Jessie. Also buster could be running networkmanager instead of networking to manage connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to think that this is a meaningful command to run on Debian 10, and it wasn't particularly useful on Debian 8.

And it is nothing to do with the systemd doco, as this service is not supplied by the systemd people.
It is supplied by the `ifupdown` package.

On Debian 8 there is no explicit `networking.service` unit.
The service by that name was an auto-generated unit wrapping [the van Smoorenburg `/etc/init.d/networking` script](https://sources.debian.org/src/ifupdown/0.7.53.1/debian/networking.init/).
The van Smoorenburg `rc` script had "reload" semantics, which the generator will have picked up on, but they were little different from a simple restart.

On Debian 10 there is [an explicit `networking.service` unit](https://sources.debian.org/src/ifupdown/0.8.35/debian/networking.service/), but it is a single-shot service marked as remaining running after the service process has exited.
It is not given any meaningful "reload" semantics; there being no `ExecReload` in the service definition and no process to signal.
`networking.service` can only be meaningfully started, stopped, and restarted.
It has no "reload".

Comment: Thanks ! It seems like the Debian 10 `networking.service` is completely unrelated to Debian 8's. So triggering would be simply `sudo /etc/init.d/networking reload`, right? (This was done in ansible , so a simple `command` will probably suffice)

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

From [systemd(1)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html):

> reload PATTERN…
>
> Asks all units listed on the command line to reload their configuration. Note that this will reload the service-specific configuration, not the unit configuration file of systemd. ... In other words: for the example case of Apache, this will reload Apache's httpd.conf in the web server, not the apache.service systemd unit file. ...

For a service unit to support the `reload` option, it must implement `ExecReload=`.

You'll see `systemctl cat apache2.service` does support that.

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
...
```

Meanwhile `systemctl cat networking.service` does not:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment
ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo
RemainAfterExit=true
...
```

Looking at a debian 7 (wheezy) machine I have, I see that it doesn't have systemd yet.  In `/etc/init.d/networking` it's clear that `reload` is supported just does an `ifdown` followed by `ifup`

```
# /etc/init.d/networking (on Debian 7 wheezy)
...
reload)
    process_options

    log_action_begin_msg "Reloading network interfaces configuration"
    state=$(cat /run/network/ifstate)
    ifdown -a --exclude=lo $verbose || true
    if ifup --exclude=lo $state $verbose ; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
    ;;
...
```

I don't have a debian 8 (jessie) machine lying around, but I bet that it introduces `systemd` but not everything had been migrated yet.  I suspect if you `systemctl cat networking`, you'll see `ExecReload=/etc/init.d/networking reload` where later releases don't rely on these init scripts anymore.